# Python Parsing: Pull data from html test file for non-standard layout

Tags: python, text, html-parsing, text-parsing

I need help with parsing an html text file that has a layout that I'm not sure how to parse through, and could really use the help.

**code thus far:**

```
import urllib,os, urllib2, webbrowser, StringIO, re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen

urlfile = open('output.txt','r')

html = urlfile

soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(html))

print soup.prettify()
table = soup.find('table', id="dgProducts__ctl2_lblCountry")
rows = table.findAll('<span id="dgProducts__ctl2_lblCountry">')

for tr in rows:
  cols = tr.findAll('td')
for td in cols:
   text = ''.join(td.find(text=True))
   print text+"|",
print
```

**What I'm Trying to Do:**
I'm looking to extract the data from the .html text file and have it presented in the following format:

```
Header Row:  Country Company Name  Company Product Name       Status
Data Row(s): 1        Ace           Desktop      Ace Vision    Gold
```

abbreviated .html file Data Structure:

```
</tr><tr bgcolor="White">
  <td><font color="#330099" size="1">
         <span><font size="2">
           <input id="dgProducts__ctl12_ckCompare" type="checkbox" name="dgProducts:_ctl12:ckCompare" onclick="checkSelected(this.form, this);" />
           </font></span>
        </font></td><td><font color="#330099" size="1">
         <span id="dgProducts__ctl12_lblModel1"><font size="2">  
          <a href='ProductDisplay.aspx?return=pm&action=view&search=true&productid=4592&ProductType=1&epeatcountryid=1'>Ace Vision 7HS</a></font></span>
        </font></td><td><font color="#330099" size="1">
         <span id="dgProducts__ctl12_lblCountry">United States</span>
        </font></td><td><font color="#330099" size="1">
         <span id="dgProducts__ctl12_lblProductCategory1"><font size="2">Desktops</font></span>
        </font></td><td><font color="#330099" size="1">
         <span id="dgProducts__ctl12_lblRating1"><font size="2">Gold</font></span>
        </font></td><td><font color="#330099" size="1">
         <span id="dgProducts__ctl12_lblPoints1">18</span>
        </font></td><td><font color="#330099" size="1">
         <span id="dgProducts__ctl12_lblEnergyStar">5.0</span>
        </font></td><td><font color="#330099" size="1">
         <span id="dgProducts__ctl12_lblMonitorType1"><font size="2"></font></span>
        </font></td><td><font color="#330099" size="1">
         <span id="dgProducts__ctl12_lblMonitorSize"><font size="2"></font></span>
        </font></td><td><font color="#330099" size="1">
         <span id="dgProducts__ctl12_lblListingDate1"><font size="2">3/16/2010</font></span>
        </font></td><td><font color="#330099" size="1">
         <span id="dgProducts__ctl12_lblStatus"><font size="2">Active</font></span>
        </font></td><td><font color="#330099" size="1">
         <span id="dgProducts__ctl12_lblExceptions" align="center"><a href='#' onclick=ShowExceptions('Exceptions.aspx?id=4592');>    
          <img src='http://www.epeat.net/Images/inform.gif' title='Click to view exceptions' alt='Click to view exceptions' border='0'></a></span>
        </font></td>
```

Comment: Just stumbled upon `''.join(html)` instead of `html.read()`.  Well, to each his own :)

Comment: "code thus far"... "What I'm Trying to Do"... And?  What doesn't work?  What problem are you having?  What help do you need?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you use the module called MiniDom or xml.dom.minidom. It makes it easy to parse XML and HTML files.